# Trigger a java jar file when a file is modified in the Linux headless machine

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, executable-jar

I need to trigger a java jar file whenever a file (**report.html**) is updated in linux headless machine.

```
java -jar readReport.jar
```

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor

Comment: `inotifywait` should work

Comment: Thank you. I am new to linux, could you please share a example of how to use inotifywait for this case.

Comment: Google `monitor file change linux`. This question is a duplicate.

Comment: https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch seems like the best, cross-platform option.

Answer (score 0):

As I am new to Linux just gave a try with inotifywait, please check if this is correct

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify <path-to-report.html> 
do
  java -jar readReport.jar
done
```

Will this check continuously for the update in a loop and whenever there is an update of (report.html) this jar has to be executed.